# PHP Session variables are not passing to a second page even if it has **session_start()** on both pages

Tags: php, arrays, session, session-variables

This is the first application I do that has a DB and PHP, so I'll expect some errors on it, but I couldn't figure what I'm doing wrong with this one.

I'm trying to pass the username from a login HTML form using JS/JQuery, into a PHP file that will verify the username and will store the content from the DB into some $_SESSION variables. 
In other words, I just want to verify some content from the login page, so I can assign a variable that will hold the entire session, until the user logout.

It works correctly in the login page and I can print the variables to the console, but when I redirect using JS to a second page, after the PHP user verification, but the variables appear empty in the second page.

In the research I did, I found that both pages should have:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

But even after that change, the array $_SESSION is empty.

I also confirmed the status of the session:

```
<?php session_status(); ?> //This result in a 2, meaning that it's working.
```

And the ID is the same in both pages.

As this is a larger project, I wanted to be sure that anything else was bothering with this, so I've recreated this as a smaller project and I'm still having the problem. This is what I have in the files:

### Index.php

I stripped as much as possible and to verify if the problem persisted. 
Here is the PHP/HTML form and also the JQUERY script that overrides the button functionality to do what I need.

This is the begining of the file:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

Then the BODY:

```
<body class="bg-light">
  <div class="flex-row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4" >
      <form class="card" method="post">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">User</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="" autocomplete="username">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pssw">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pssw" placeholder="" autocomplete="current-password">
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <button class="text-center btn btn-primary" id="btn-login">Enter</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div>
        This is the ID of the session: <?php echo session_id(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

### JQuery script

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btn-login").click(function(){
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: "mylogin.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          name: $("#username").val(),
          pssw: $("#pssw").val(),
        },
        success: function(data){
          if (data == true){
            $(location).attr('href', '/page2.php');
          }
        }
      });
    });
  })
```

### Mylogin.php

Here I got the variables from the JQuery script, verify if the user and password are 'a' and then assign the $_SESSION variables.

```
<?php

$rawUser = $_POST['name'];
$rawPssw = $_POST['pssw'];

if($rawUser == "a" && $rawPssw == "a"){
  $_SESSION["username"]  = $rawUser;
  $_SESSION["another"]  = "New Test";
  echo true;
} else {
  echo false;
}
?>
```

### Page2.php

The purpose of this one is just to print the variables, but they are **empty.**

Again this is the first line of the file:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

And then the body:

```
<body class="bg-light">
  <section class="container" id="login">
    <div class="flex-row d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4" >
        <h1>This is the second page</h1>
        <div>
          <?php echo "Session status: " . session_status(); ?>
        </div>
        <div>
          <?php echo "Name: " . $_SESSION["username"]; ?>
        </div>
        <div>
          <?php echo "Role: " . $_SESSION["pssw"]; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

What I will expect is that the variables like **$_SESSION['name']** will hold any value assigned to them by the PHP file, when the second page is loaded. That way I will be able to set up the display of some elements depending on the login of the user.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you developing this on localhost?  Do you have a development domain configured?  Sessions use cookies, and if you don't have a valid domain there are often problems with the cookie.

Comment: does mylogin.php have <?php session_start(); ?> at the top too?

Comment: Make sure you can see any errors that might be occurring ~ [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: @Robot70: added it to the **mylogin.php** and it started working. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED: I was missing the session_start() in the begining of the **mylogin.php** file. Thanks to @Robot70 for noticing it.